# exclude files from a list with certain length

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to print list of filenames after certain length being exclude. Below is what I have so far.

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

path=r'Directory'
files=glob.glob(path + '/**/*.cod',recursive=True)

for i in files:
    indat = pd.read_csv(i, skiprows=4, header=None, engine='python')
    a=indat[8]
    if len(a) >= 600:
       print() #want a list of file names that the files that have length >=600.
```

Comment: Have you tried `print(i)` ?

Comment: @KaanE. Thank you!  It work.

Comment: no pb feel free to accept my answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time you come to `len(a) > 600` you already filtered out files that are less than 600 so you should simply change your code to following:

```py
for i in files:
    indat = pd.read_csv(i, skiprows=4, header=None, engine='python')
    a=indat[8]
    if len(a) >= 600:
       print(i)
```